# Splitting Audio Configurations for One Output into Separate Audio Outputs

Tags: sound, games, output

I have a Razer Kraken headset which on Windows splits into two separate outputs - Game and Chat - by default so that you can separately adjust volumes and outputs for your games and your voice chat apps. On Linux game and chat are a configuration of the one output and so I cannot do this. How could I split the two configurations into separate sound outputs that I could use for separate programs? Thanks!

Ubuntu 22.04.4 Jammy Jellyfish

Comment: Make the title more specific